# How to add a script to a page on the public internet?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, testing, browser

I would like to test what would happen if I were to add a script that I wrote myself to a page on the public internet that I'm viewing in a web browser, such as Internet Explorer (in this specific case).

This is not something I would want to do in a production system, but I would like to test a page-enhancing script with many existing pages.  I do not want to modify the page in any way for other viewers, I just want to see what would happen if my script were to become part of the page.

It would be fine if there were some tool that could be used to intercept the page from the server before loading it into the browser and add the script tag there.

It would also be good to be able to modify the page in the browser itself, though this would probably be less desirable as there might be a different way to do this in each browser.

I do realize that I could simply download a page manually with all its related resources and then run a modified copy from a local server, but that would be rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fiddler to manipulate responses between the server and your client / browser, adding in arbitrary javascript (for example) through "FiddlerScript".

See: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse for more info

For example, you can replace a specific Javascript with another via:

```
if (oSession.PathAndQuery=="/version1.js") {
  oSession["x-replywithfile"] ="version2.js";
}
```

In the OnBeforeResponse event